# React how to update the data in App.js from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React App. I don't have a backend server. Instead, I used a .json file called `securities.json` as the backend server. The .json file list the securities and the price list in each security.

What I am attempting to do is to submit the updated price list to the securities.json on App.js, a parent component, from its child component. I noticed that when I add a new price in the Price Popup window and then close it but rechecked the Price Popup window again. The new price that I entered disappeared. I couldn't figure out how to solve it. I'm trying to pass it up to App.js as one developer suggested.

Can someone please take a look at my code in CodeSandBox?
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa

Comment: I can't get it to work correctly, keep getting an error about `closePopup()` not being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Use Redux: https://react-redux.js.org/
2. Use reacts context system: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

you can also pass an update function as props to your child component which updates the state of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is price list is set in constructor. There the state is set from props. On change of props, the price list state is not updated as setting state happens in constructor which executed only once. You need to update state when ever props get changed.

This is the code I am talking about

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      priceArr: this.props.pricelist,
      // newPriceArr: this.props.updatePrice,
      showPricePopup: false,
      addPricePopup: false,
      isToggleOn: true,
      date: props.date || "",
      number: props.number || ""
    };
  }
```

You may need to use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to set state when props change.